# Start VLC with Playback Speed Increased

Tags: vlc, playback

I know that I can change the setting for playback in settings and this will affect vlc globally. However, I don't want EVERY file to be played faster, only mp4 files. Therefore, I figure I can setup a separate application .desktop file with a custom command that can set the playback speed on start.

Does anybody know the configuration setting in command-line to increase playback speed? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is add the `--rate` switch after `vlc` and specify the value you want or have tested in `vlc` previously; for example, from the command line I could play a file with

```
vlc --rate 3 myfile.mp4
```

So `vlc --rate 3` (substitute 3 for the value you want) is the key part of what you need for your launcher.

More command-line options for `vlc` are available by entering in the terminal `vlc -h`, or `vlc -H` for exhaustive help.

I don't know which desktop you are on, but on **Xfce** I create a very simple vlc mp4 launcher `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` in this format (and make it executable):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=vlcmp4launcher
Comment=vlcx3
Exec=/usr/bin/vlc --rate 3 %U
Terminal=false
```

Then simply go to your file browser and right click an mp4 file, select this launcher, and check the box to make sure that all mp4s are opened with this `.desktop` application from now on. Now just clicking the video file will make it play using your custom parameters, but will leave unaffected any other video file that `vlc` plays.

This is the quickest way to associate your launcher with the filetype, but to do it manually you would edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the name of your launcher. As an example, you would add `video/mp4=vlcmp4.desktop` to the [Default Applications] section and the [Added Associations list] section should have `video/mp4=vlc.desktop;vlcmp4.desktop;`.

More information on `.desktop` files and launchers is [here at the Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: [Fine tune with `AltGr+` `[` or `]`](https://www.vlchelp.com/controlling-playback-speed-vlc-media-player/).